# python selective joining of list to get a string

Tags: python-3.x, list

Lets say I have a list in python like :

```
['ann', 'nne', 'nef', 'efr', 'fra', 'ran', 'ank', 'nk']
```

Is it possible to use list join to selectively add elements of a list. For example I add the full element0, but for other elements of the list I just add the last character(also I add the last character of element only if its length is3). so the string becomes:

```
"ann"+"e"+"f"+"r"+"a"+"n"+"k"= annefrank
```

The last element is not added as its not of length 3.
I can solve this using for loop, but would like to know if there is any optimized pythonic way of doing this or using join.

Thank you in anticipation.
AIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have certain requirements you need to apply some custom logic anyway, regardless of the paradigm that you choose.

I would use Python's functional tools for filtering the sequence:

```
import operator
import functools

seq = ['ann', 'nne', 'nef', 'efr', 'fra', 'ran', 'ank', 'nk']

functools.reduce(operator.add, (map(lambda x: x[-1], filter(lambda x: len(x)==3, seq[1:]))), seq[0])
# gives annefrank
```

The inner `filter` takes care of elements which are not of length 3, except the first element of the list. The `map` will return their last character and the `reduce` will apply `add` over them with first element of the list as the initial value.

You can also do it with `join` if you prefer:

```
seq[0]+''.join((map(lambda x: x[-1], filter(lambda x: len(x)==3, seq[1:]))))
# gives annefrank
```

You can also merge the filter into the map:

```
seq[0]+''.join((map(lambda x: x[-1] if len(x)==3 else '', seq[1:])))
```

As you see there are many ways to achieve what you want to do. However I will prefer `map` and `filter` over looping over a sequence since they have highly optimized implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a list of the third letter from each item in the list:

```
    mylist = ['ann', 'nne', 'nef', 'efr', 'fra', 'ran', 'ank', 'nk']
    thirdletters = [ x[2:3] for x in mylist ]
```

(the final item in that new list will be an empty string because there is no third letter in 'nk') then collect those letters into a string by using `join` with an empty string as the filler:

```
    thirdstring = ''.join(thirdletters)
```

and then finally add that string after the first two letters of the first item from the original list:

```
    result = mylist[0][:2] + thirdstring
```

If that's too wordy, you can jam it all together into one statement:

```
    result = mylist[0][:2] + ''.join( [ x[2:3] for x in mylist ] )
```